# Same code for iOS, Android and Windows Tablet

Tags: android, ios, tablet-pc

Is it possible to write the same application for different kinds of Tablet PC? The application should be able to access the camera of the tablet and it's peripheral devices (like a printer).
If it is possible then with what languages/technologies/libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are libraries to develop cross platform apps. The most common ones are [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/), [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/start/) and [Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com/). I have worked only with Rhodes , so I can't really tell how good or bad the other two are. Rhodes is a ruby framework and can be used to develop apps on iOS, Android, Windows and Symbian.

This article should really help you out. Its a comparison between App Inventor, DroidDraw, Rhodes, PhoneGap, Appcelerator, WebView, and AML.  http://www.amlcode.com/2010/07/16/comparison-appinventor-rhomobile-phonegap-appcelerator-webview-and-aml/

Answer (score 0):

Try [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/start/)

> Its an open-source mobile development framework developed by Nitobi
>   Software. It enables software programmers to build applications for
>   mobile devices using JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS3, instead of often
>   less-known languages such as Objective-C.
>
> PhoneGap currently supports development for the operating systems
>   Apple iOS, Google Android, HP webOS, Microsoft Windows Mobile, Nokia
>   Symbian OS and RIM BlackBerry.